# Create column by grouping on one column and incremental addition with another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new column 'newCol' that will group on colA, then use first value in colC in each group for incremental adding. Example  below:

Original DF

```
ColA         ColB        ColC
bird          55          5  
bird          34          5
bird          .6          5
cat           422         20
cat           1.9         20
frog          5.77        100
frog          6           100
frog          68          100
frog          44          100
```

Desired DF   -- say the "incremental value" I want to use is 10 to build 'newCol'

```
ColA         ColB        ColC      newCol
bird          55          5          5
bird          34          5          15
bird          .6          5          25
cat           422         20         20
cat           1.9         20         30
frog          5.77        100        100
frog          6           100        110
frog          68          100        120
frog          44          100        130
```

I can do this with creating a dictionary via looping through the dataframe and mapping it back to the DF, but it's a lot of lines for something that I'm hoping to do more simply with a line or two. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `cumcount`

```
df['newCol'] = df.groupby('ColA').cumcount().mul(10).add(df['ColC'])
```

```
>>> df
   ColA    ColB  ColC  newCol
0  bird   55.00     5       5
1  bird   34.00     5      15
2  bird    0.60     5      25
3   cat  422.00    20      20
4   cat    1.90    20      30
5  frog    5.77   100     100
6  frog    6.00   100     110
7  frog   68.00   100     120
8  frog   44.00   100     130
```